# slideUp and slideDown, delay issue (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, delay, slidedown, slideup

The class (heady) is supposed to slideUp when the document percentage height is below 25%, and then if you scroll up it will appear with a delay of 1400ms. The issue is that this should occur again, the class will not slideUp again.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var lastScrollTop   = 0,
        delta           = 5;

$( window ).scroll(function(event) {

    var scrollTop        = $( this ).scrollTop(),
        scrollAmount     = $( window ).scrollTop(),
        documentHeight   = $( document ).height(),
        scrollPercent    = ( scrollAmount / documentHeight ) * 100;



    if ( Math.abs( lastScrollTop - scrollTop ) <= delta )
        return;

    // scroller
    if ( scrollTop > lastScrollTop && scrollPercent > 25 )
    {
        $( '.heady' ).slideUp(600);                             // scroll down code
    }
    else if ( scrollTop < lastScrollTop)
    {
        $( '.heady' ).delay(1300)                               // scroll up code
                     .slideDown(600);
    };

    lastScrollTop = scrollTop;

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the up/down animation using CSS translateY instead. That way you're adding/removing a class on the heady element which will effectively 'reset' the scroll allowing the scroll animation to fire each time.

This is how I handle the majority of my animations unless I HAVE to JS use for whatever reason.